# React-Native:Not getting state data after returning from Reducer

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am writing few components for a react native app. Here I encountered an issue which I am not able to explain.

Here is a component's render method -

```
return (
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(event)=>this.selectedCurrentItem()} >
<View style={CardItemStyle.containerStyle}>
<Text style={CardItemStyle.titleStyle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
<Text style={CardItemStyle.bodyStyle}>{this.props.description}</Text>
<Image source={{uri:this.props.uri}} style={CardItemStyle.imgStyle}></Image>
</View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   )
```

If the user presses on the component then this method will be invoked -

```
selectedCurrentItem(){      
this.props.singleSelection({id:this.props.id,fullData:this.props.dataList.fullData});
 console.log(this.props);
 Actions.CardForm({id:this.props.SingleSelection.id});
}
```

If you notice above, there is a call to SingleSelection, which is basically the action creator, which in turn calls this reducer -

```
const INITIAL_STATE={fullData:[]};

export default  SingleSelection=(state=INITIAL_STATE,action)=>{
switch(action.type){
case "singleItem": 
selectedObject=action.payload.fullData.filter((item)=>{ return 
item.id===action.payload.id});

return {...state,selected:selectedObject};
 default: return state;
}
}
```

The call to the reducer goes fine and I am able to check that through debugger.

Problem is with this line (trying to navigate to a different component)-

```
 Actions.CardForm({id:this.props.SingleSelection.id});
```

in the method 'selectedCurrentItem'.

I am not getting the state data returned from the Reducer.
So,

```
    this.props.SingleSelection.id
```

is not having any value

Note that, I have the following Combine reducer -

```
export default combineReducers({
    dataList:dataList,
    SingleSelection:SingleSelection
})
```

Here is the mapstateToProps and connect from the same component -

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return state;
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,{singleSelection})(CardItem);
```

**Is there a problem if I try to access the state immediately after calling the action/Reducer?**

Please let me know if I need to provide any other details.

Comment: Could you please share a repo with a reproducible code?

Comment: Please also show how you call connect from react-redux, and the definition of mapStateToProps

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops-object

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
The problem was this function-

```
selectedCurrentItem(){      
this.props.singleSelection({id:this.props.id,fullData:this.props.dataList.fullData});
  Actions.CardForm({id:this.props.SingleSelection.id});
}
```

In the first line, I am calling the action creator to set state.
Immediately after that I am trying to access the state data. 
Immediately accessing the state data will not return just updated state information.